# Reference types as parameters

Tags: c#

So I was reading Jon Skeet's C# in depth and came across some myths like Reference types are always passed by ref, So I decided to do a little experiment myself.

As you can see in the following code I have a simple Car class with one property which is initialized to 500 when the constructor is called. I also have the NullIt function which assigns null to the parameter value and a SpeedUp method which just changes the Speed property value.

Examining the main method you can see I instantiate a Car object, then I pass the object to the static SpeedUp method and the Speed value changes to 1000 but when I'm passing it to the also static NullIt method the object remains intact. From this the only thing I can assume is that the object is passed by value and the fields / properties are passed by reference. Is this right?

I know that if I pass it using the ref keyword will return null.

```
  class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car c = new Car();
        Car.SpeedUP(c);
        Car.NullIt(c);
    }

    class Car
    {
        public int Speed { get; set; }

        public Car() { Speed = 500; }


        public static void SpeedUP(Car c)
        {
            c.Speed = 1000;
        }

        public static void NullIt(Car c)
        {
            c = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In C# you always pass by value unless you explicitly use `ref` or `out`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From this the only thing I can assume is that the object is passed by
>   value and the fields / properties are passed by reference. Is this
>   right?

Not really. **Object's address is passed by value.**

So when you do:

```
Car.SpeedUP(c);
```

Now your parameter of method `SpeedUp` and your field `c` in caller, both point to the same location in memory. Thus changing the property works.

But for your call:

```
Car.NullIt(c);
```

Your method parameter `c` and caller's `c` both points to same location. But since you assign null to your parameter `c` , now it is not pointing to any memory location, but the original/caller's `c` still points to the same memory location.

Consider the following:

When you pass parameter to your method then two references in memory would be pointing to the same address like:

[image]

But when you assign `null` it doesn't change the other reference.

[image]

The first reference *(in caller)* still points to the same location, only the method parameter is now pointing to `null`.

Comment: I get it and I don't. If both c's point to the same location, shouldn't the changes made reflect to the same location?

Comment: @allocator, no, you are assigning `null` to the parameter reference. Suppose the object is at memory address `0x100`, So at first your caller's `c` is holding `0x100`, later when you pass it as parameter, now your method's parameter is holding `0x100`. But when you do `methodParameter C = null`, that will **only** change the method parameter, so instead of `0x100` now it will be holding `null`. The caller's `c` remained un-affected.

Comment: Understood it a little better, I believe I will get it better as I gain more experience with the language. marked as answer!

Comment: Don't worry; this stuff makes no sense at first, but makes perfect sense eventually. When you say `c = ...` you are not changing *the thing at the location* (your object). You are only changing *what memory location c is referring to*. What makes this confusing is that this appears to be different treatment from how primitives like `int`, `long` work. But THOSE are not address-types pointing to some other location; they're just values themselves.

Comment: In addition: If at some point you start working with `struct`s, those use the much more familiar concepts of simply having the memory 'in' the variable. So, if you pass a struct into a method, make changes to it, and continue, those changes will *not* be present afterward as they would for an `object` instance of a `class`; just like if you did with an integer.

Comment: @Katana314, well stucts and `int` are value types and that is why they behave same. Infact `System.Int32` or `int` is a structure

Answer (score 0):

When you call `NullIt()` you are passing the *value* of a reference to your instance of `Car`. You then change this value to null. However, the original copy of that value remains intact. Exactly the same way passing the value of an `int` works - you can modify your local copy without affecting the "original".

If you were to change that to `NullIt(ref Car c)`, you would be passing a reference to the reference, and hence setting it to null would set the original value of the reference to null. That last part can be a bit of a mind bender, but it's so rarely necessary (if ever) that you don't need to worry too much about it.

Comment: yeap I knew about the ref keyword, my question came from the odd behavior I couldn't really get.

Comment: @allocator does it make sense now?

Comment: trying to understand it better!

Answer (score 0):

> From this the only thing I can assume is that the object is passed by value and the fields / properties are passed by reference. Is this right?

While the observed effect may look like this, the way you describe it has some incorrect implications: The fields/properties are not "passed by reference" in a way that there is a reference to each field/property. It is rather that *the reference to the object* is passed by value.

That is why by accessing any member of the object, or the object itself, you are accessing the very same instance you passed into the method, not a copy thereof.

However, the variable `c` itself is a reference, and that reference is passed by value. That is why, in your methods, you cannot change that reference by assigning a new value and expect that the variable `c` itself now has a new value (in your case `null`).

Answer (score 0):

It IS a bit confusing, because the word *reference* is overloaded (has two subtly different meanings).

When describing types as either value types or reference types. it means one thing, 
Whether the data for the state of an object of that type is stored on the *stack*, (which is a section of memory that methods have access to) or whether it is stored on another section of memory called the *Heap*, and only the address of that section of heap is then stored on the stack, allowing code to only access the object indirectly.

When describing whether parameter values are passed to a method by value or by reference, otoh, it means something different. It means whether the actual value of the parameter is [copied and] passed to the method, or whether the address of the parameter value's memory slot is passed.

So you can actually have four combinations here:

1. Pass a value type by value -   The value is copied and passed  to
   the method. The method cannot change the source value.
2. Pass a reference type by value.  The address of the reference type
   (which is on the Heap) is copied and passed. The method cannot
   change the address in the source variable, but it CAN change the
   data on the HEAP that the address points to.
3. Pass a value type by reference. The method gets the address of the
   source object, (on the stack) and can change that source value.
4. Pass a reference type by reference.  The method gets the address of
   the variable (on the stack) that contains the address of the object
   itself (on the Heap). The method can change the data in the source
   object, AND CAN ALSO CHANGE WHICH OBJECT (ON THE HEAP) THE SOURCE
   VARIABLE POINTS TO)

Comment: The stack and heap bit is irrelevant and wrong: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: So to get this right 
let's say that the caller variable points to X and it's address is Y
when I pass it to the method the method's variable get's the X address  and that's why I can manipulate the properties and so.

And when I use the ref keyword Y address is passed.

Right ?

Comment: Eric's blog is (if you understand what he is talking about) technically correct, but by adding another overload for the word reference (to mean address value), this is even more confusing for a novice or initiate. For the purposes of the discussion here, the distinction is not necessary.  Except for those distinctions, the state for a an object created from a value type is stored on the stack (ok, or on a register), and the state for a reference type is stored on the Heap.

Comment: what Eric calls references are just addresses of some memory location.  When we declare any variable, we allocate memory on the stack (again, ok, or in a register) to hold something...  for a reference type, this memory will hold a null, and/or when/if initialized with new operator it will hold the address on the heap of the block of memory allocated to hold the state for that instantiated object.

Comment: Where an object is stored in memory is irrelevant to the value type/reference type distinction. Also, it is wrong, because value types *can be, but aren't necessarily* stored on the heap. For example, value typed class members aren't. Also, literally the first sentence in that post refers to how [References are not addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx)

Comment: Correction: [...] value types can be, but aren't necessarily stored on the  **stack**